cryptroot-unlock times out with 'Error: Timeout reached while waiting for askpass.'
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 with an lvm full-disk encryption setup on a Dell Precision Tower 3620 (the harddisk is a FireCuda PCIe v4)
I use the cryptroot-unlock command on boot via SSH to unlock the drive and start up Ubuntu. This has been successful since installation a few months ago.
Today, however rather than getting a prompt when I run cryptroot-unlock, I get the error message:
Error: Timeout reached while waiting for askpass

Running cryptroot-unlock with the -x parameter with ash -x /usr/bin/cryptroot-unlock I get some very verbose information and it appears that the askpass command isn't running nor is it accessing the /lib/cryptsetup/passfifo filehandle.
I can mock-up the askpass command and passfifo by running the following in another shell
cat /lib/cryptsetup/passfifo | /lib/cryptsetup/askpass "Please unlock disk"

But when I rerun the cryptroot-unlock command, I get:
/usr/bin/cryptroot-unlock: line 187: usleep: not found

I'm thinking there's been a bit of a mishap on the initramfs side. I am happy to concede that I may need to reinstall the OS, however I'm wondering if there's anyway to rescue the data that's currently on the system in the interim (other than going back in time and setting up a backup, I know, I'm mad at myself too).
I would really appreciate the following:

Is there a way that I can manually run cryptsetup luksOpen to unlock my drive?
If I plug in the nvme harddisk into the usb port of another linux computer (using an adapter) can I unlock the drive and save any data from there?

Additional information:
Having compared processes running to another machine with the a similar setup, I've also noticed that the process /bin/plymouth ask-for-password --prompt Please unlock disk <disk id> is also not running on my machine.

Likely you are either missing the prompt or it is getting stepped on by another message.  If you press tabl or hit return at the right time (or just start typing the password), it might reprint the prompt (or accept the recovery password).   That failing, you can mount it from a live disk.

"""
Likely you are either missing the prompt or it is getting stepped on by another message.
"""
Seems unlikely, ps | grep askpass returns nothing so there's nothing hanging.  It seems that askpass just isn't running at all

After a week, a recovery and reinstall I have figured it out!
The same issue happened today after a fresh installation, and I'd restarted successfully a few times too.
The error I could see this time in the logs before it then presented me the ash console was:
Gave up waiting for root device

It turns out that the BIOS had updated the SATA operations parameter from AHCI to Intel RST (Intel Rapid Storage Technology). Rebooting and updating the parameter in BIOS fixed the issue!
I don't know why my BIOS configuration is being spontaneously updated, I hope to figure that out in near future. In the meantime, I hope that this helps anyone who has the same issue.
Note: Changing your SATA parameter in the BIOS could result in corrupting the drive. Ubuntu doesn't strictly prohibit RST, so if your BIOS also has RST enabled it might not be your issue. If you know you have AHCI enabled on, WRITE IT ON YOUR COMPUTER, then if you see this error and see RST is enabled you will know changing the SATA parameter may solve your issue. Otherwise you're risking data loss unnecessarily.
